# How to group by the value represented in the field, not the field itself in Crystal Reports

Tags: group-by, crystal-reports

I have 10 fields in my table that represent year 1-year 10. I want to group a report by the year represented in the field, not by the field itself. For example, one result may look like this:

| Year | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 | Q4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Yr1: 2024 | Q1Y1$:200 | Q2Y1$:230 | Q3Y1$:120 | Q4Y1$:400 |
| Yr2: 2025 | Q1Y2$:100 | Q2Y2$:470 | Q3Y2$:500 | Q4Y2$:800 |
| Yr3: 2025 | Q1Y1$:210 | Q1Y1$:560 | Q1Y1$:900 | Q1Y1$:900 |

...and so on

The next result may be:

| Year | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 | Q4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Yr1: 2023 | 100 | 200 | 130 | 320 |
| Yr2: 2024 | 300 | 230 | 120 | 500 |
| Yr3: 2025 | 890 | 300 | 300 | 210 |

I want to group by the year, so that I can sum quarterly amounts for each year (i.e. 2023, 2024, etc.) This is a simple, one table report that needs to sum amounts for each quarter of each year for a couple hundred results.

I have tried creating a formula to parse out the year, but can't figure out how to group by the year value and not the field since there are 10 different year fields.